# How to implement Single Sign On using SAML 2.0 in ADX (community) Dynamics CRM Online portal

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-365, adxstudio-portals

How to enable portal for Single Sign On in Dynamics CRM online version.
We have online dynamics 365 with community portal and we also have one website from which user will login and click on community portal link.

After clicking on that link portal should in ask for user id and password and automatically it will sign in using website credential

**Application details**

Dynamics 365 Online.
ADX portal enabled (community Portal).
Website for customer (end user used to login)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post that describes how to configure ADFS and Dynamics Portal

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/microsoftdynamicscrmsolutions/archive/2016/11/11/sso-configuration-for-crm-portal